# Circles on a plane

Tags: combinatorics

$n$ circles with total area A have been drawn on the plane (overlapping circles are not counted multiple times). Prove that we can select a disjoint union of circles that has area greater than $\frac{A}{9}$.

I'm thinking that if there is a circle that has an area that is greater than 1/9 then we're basically done. But if not AND the statement is false then we must be full of overlaps. More specifically a point has been covered by at least 9 circles.

Comment: Funny problem; I like it. Where does it come from? Why do you think it's true? What have you tried?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  This is the same as being able to cover a table with 10 dots on it by 10 circles. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/covering-ten-dots-on-a-table-with-ten-equal-sized-coins-explanation-of-proof) very instructive.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, @Shailesh.

Comment: @Shailesh Why is that the same?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the circles in order of decreasing radius. We greedily accept each circle if it does not overlap any previously accepted circle.

Now, if we accept a disk of radius $r$, we will disallow any disk that intersects it (which must have radius $\leq r$), all of which are completely covered by a disk of radius $3r$.

Therefore, we cover $\pi r^2$ with our chosen disk, while disallowing at most $\pi (3r)^2$ in area from $A$. In other words, we cumulatively cover a total area of at least $\frac{A}{9}$.